# Email notification in java

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am developing Escalation Tracking System.In my application I have to send email notification(automatically depending on some criteria), if deadlines are approaching for some escalation.This is a web based application. Im using servlet jsp. Can anybody tell me how can achieve the email notification stuff.

thanx in advance!

Comment: If you want to do it automatically you'll need to set up a timer on your web server that can run the code at the desired interval (probably daily?). Your exact options in terms of timer to use depend on the web server you're using, though.

Comment: hi Anthony, im using APACHE TOMCAT, does it handle that?if yes can you plz explain how to configure that.

Comment: You can set up a timer in Tomcat, but I don't use it so I can't help you with configuring a timer for it - Google is going to be your friend for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Mail api to achieve this.Follow these steps in your code to send Email.

1. Set SMTP host properties

   ```
     Properties props = System.getProperties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", yoursmtpServer);
   ```
2. Get Session

   ```
     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
   ```
3. Create message and set sender and reciever

   ```
     Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
     msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
     msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
   ```
4. Set subject and other details and then send

   ```
     msg.setSubject(subject);
     msg.setText(body);
    // -- Set some other header information --
     msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "ABCMail");
     msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    // -- Send the message --
     Transport.send(msg);
   ```

I think it would help you.

EDIT :  You can use Servlet  filter or any timer to check the logic.

Timer logic.

- Use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to implement you timer.
- Create your task by implement Runnable .
- Put you logic in you run()
- timer.schedule(task, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);